# Изменить значения input range js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте, у меня есть `input type='range'`.
 С помощью js я задаю ему значения `max`, `min`, `value`. Так вот, хочу чтобы значение по умолчанию стало максимальным, но даже при value=(максимальное значение) инпут находится на минимальном значении.
 Не могу понять почему.
Вот код, который у меня в проекте.

```js
const randomValue = (min, max) => {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
};

const setPrice = () => {
  let slider = document.getElementById('price');
  let minPriceField = document.getElementById('price-range-min-field');
  let maxPriceField = document.getElementById('price-range-max-field');
  let minPriceValue = randomValue(5000, 15000);
  let maxPriceValue = randomValue(25000, 50000);

  minPriceField.textContent = minPriceValue;
  maxPriceField.textContent = maxPriceValue;

  slider.setAttribute('min', minPriceValue);
  slider.setAttribute('max', maxPriceValue);
  slider.setAttribute('value', maxPriceValue);
}

setPrice();
```

```html
<fieldset className='products-filter-group'>
  <label htmlFor='price-range'>Максимальная цена</label><br/>
  <span className='price-range-min' id='price-range-min-field'>1000</span>
  <input type='range' id='price' name='price-range' />
  <span className='price-range-max' id='price-range-max-field'>5000</span>
</fieldset>
```

В демке все работает как надо, инпут принимает максимальное значение после того как `setAttribute` срабатывает.
 Но у меня в `react` проекте, почему-то на установку атрибута `value` вообще нет реакции `slider.setAttribute('value', maxPriceValue)`.
 Есть у кого-нибудь идеи по поводу этого? Может я допускаю где-то ошибку?

### UPD

Только до меня дошло, что можно поменять значение через `slider.value = value`, но почему через аттрибут `value` не хочет меняться, объясните пожалуйста?) Хотя опять же в демке меняется... не понятно

### Закрыто

Comment: Вы не можете знать почему метод не работает пока вы не покажете исходный код.

Comment: @RomanC так в том то и дело, что я скопировал код из своего проекта... Единственное отличие - это то, что в проекте я вызываю функцию `setPrice()` в компоненте, который отрисовывает блок с этим инпутом. В `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Понимаю, что нужно смотреть сам проект, но какие-то странные вещи..

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('#price').addEventListener('input', setPrice)`

Запускать надо так, но если честно, не могу даже вообразить, что ты пытался реализовать

```js
const randomValue = (min, max) => {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
};

const setPrice = () => {
  let slider = document.getElementById('price');
  let minPriceField = document.getElementById('price-range-min-field');
  let maxPriceField = document.getElementById('price-range-max-field');
  let minPriceValue = randomValue(5000, 15000);
  let maxPriceValue = randomValue(25000, 50000);

  minPriceField.textContent = minPriceValue;
  maxPriceField.textContent = maxPriceValue;

  slider.setAttribute('min', minPriceValue);
  slider.setAttribute('max', maxPriceValue);
  slider.setAttribute('value', maxPriceValue);
}

document.querySelector('#price').addEventListener('input', setPrice);
```

```html
<fieldset className='products-filter-group'>
  <label htmlFor='price-range'>Максимальная цена</label><br/>
  <span className='price-range-min' id='price-range-min-field'>1000</span>
  <input type='range' id='price' name='price-range' />
  <span className='price-range-max' id='price-range-max-field'>5000</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: После того как я получаю данные товаров по API мне нужно в форме указать минимальную и максимальную цену. Также чтобы в `input range` `value` было равно максимальной цене. Все это должно произойти сразу после того как форма отрисовалась на странице, а не по изменению инпута

Comment: Ты дважды запускаешь одну и туже функцию...  Я с трудом понимаю,  что ты хотел изобразить...  А случайный выбор диапазона цен тут к чему?

Comment: Я же написал, что я хотел изобразить. Случайный диапазон цен здесь для примера, в проекте на месте этих двух функций стоит функция нахождения максимальной и минимальной цены.